# How to create an order programmatically with bundle items in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, bundle-product, create-order

This is my script:

```
    $quote = $this->quote->create();
    $quote->setStore($store);
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

        $product = $this->product->get($order['recipeSku']);
        $params = [
            'product' => $product->getId(),
            'bundle_option' => $this->getBundleOptions($product),
            'qty' => 1
        ];
//        $product->setPrice($product->getPrice());
        $quote->addProduct($product, $params); // the quantity will always be 1(one)

    $shippingAddress = $this->getCustomerAddress($customer->getDefaultShipping());
    $billingAddress = $this->getCustomerAddress($customer->getDefaultBilling());

    //Set Address to quote
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress->getData());
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($billingAddress->getData());

    $defaultCard = $this->getDefaultVault($customer->getId());

    $quote->setPaymentMethod(AdyenCcConfigProvider::CC_VAULT_CODE);
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    $quote->save();

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData([
        'method' => AdyenCcConfigProvider::CC_VAULT_CODE,
        'public_hash' => $defaultCard->getData('public_hash'),
        'is_active_payment_token_enabler' => true,
        'purchase' => true
    ]);

    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
    $order->setEmailSent(0);


    public function getBundleOptions($product)
    {
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $bundleOptions = [];
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
            $bundleOptions[$selection->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
        return $bundleOptions;
    }
```

How can i add some bundle options as well ? This question is somehow related to this one: [Create order of 'Bundle Product' programmatically with options selection: Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/287080/6204)

Right now i m getting this message `We found an invalid request for adding product to quote.`

Thx in advance for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I figured it out. I left the script, maybe it will help someone. This works for Magento 2.4.1:

```
public function myMethod()
{
.......
    $product = $this->product->get('BUNDLE_PRODUCT_SKU');
    $params = [
        'product' => $product->getId(),
        'bundle_option' => $this->getBundleOptions($product),
        'qty' => 1
    ];
    $quote->addProduct($product, new DataObject($params));
.....
}
    public function getBundleOptions($product)
    {
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
        $bundleOptions = [];
        foreach ($selectionCollection as $selection) {
                $bundleOptions[$selection->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
        }
        return $bundleOptions;
    }
```